# Why is wp_list_authors not picking up Authors from CPT's?

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, author, list-authors

Why is `wp_list_authors` not picking up Authors from CPT's when I have the `supports` option enabled? From what I have read elsewhere it looks like I have everything covered but the authors of CPT's refuse to show. I am trying to get the default post and CPT authors to show in one unified list. Could someone show me what I am doing wrong?

**FUNCTIONS.PHP**

```
// Registers a new post type
add_action( 'init', 'message_init' );

function message_init() {
$labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Messages', 'post type general name', 'site' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Message', 'post type singular name', 'site' ),
    'menu_name'          => _x( 'Messages', 'admin menu', 'site' ),
    'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Message', 'add new on admin bar', 'site' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'message', 'site' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Message', 'site' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Message', 'site' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Message', 'site' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Message', 'site' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Messages', 'site' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Messages', 'site' ),
    'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Messages:', 'site' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No messages found.', 'site' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No messages found in Trash.', 'site' ),
);

$args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'site' ),
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'connect/series/message' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'post-formats' ),
    'taxonomies'         => array( 'category' )
);

    register_post_type( 'message', $args );
}
```

**PAGE WHERE AUTHORS ARE TO DISPLAY**

```
<div class="authors_content">
        <h5>Authors</h5>
        <ul>
            <?php $args = array(
                'orderby'       => 'post_count', 
                'order'         => 'DESC', 
                'number'        => 5,
                'exclude_admin' => false, 
                'show_fullname' => false
            );
            wp_list_authors( $args ); ?>
            <li><a href="#">View All</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**CPT Template DECLARATION**

```
/*
Template Name: Message Template
Template Post Type: post, messages
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one thing, 'DSC' is incorrect for the 'order' parameter. It should be 'DESC.'

Comment: Thanks that was a typo on my end but this does not address the issue.

Comment: If your authors haven't written any posts yet, you may need to set 'hide_empty" to false. Assuming that they have written posts, then the above code should output a list of all authors-with-posts at your site. Is it?

Comment: Thanks for replying. You are correct that a name will show using the above code if there is a post that is associated with a user (I have already tried setting `hide_empty => false`. However, I am trying to get the `wp_list_authors()` function to list authors for the default post type as well as custom post types.

Comment: well, wp_list_authors with 'hide_empty' => false should list all users with post-authoring capacities. In a mostly default WP installation, if your Message writers are listed as "Authors" under Users, they should should also come up. You could also check against or substitute the results of a get_users query.